# Creating new page/tab in groups section not working!

Tags: pages, buddypress

I'm trying to add a new tab/page in the groups page.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Groups Links
Description: Add links to the groups page.
Author: Thomas Clayson
*/
function add_groups_links_page(){
    global $bp;

    $groups_link = $bp->root_domain . '/' . $bp->groups->slug . '/' . $bp->groups->current_group->slug . '/';

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
       'name' => 'Links',
       'slug' => 'group-links',
       'parent_url' => $groups_link,
       'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->slug,
       'screen_function' => 'group_links_function_to_show_screen',
       'position' => 40 ) );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'add_groups_links_page');

function group_links_function_to_show_screen() {

    add_action( 'bp_template_title', 'group_links_function_to_show_screen_title' );
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'group_links_function_to_show_screen_content' );

    $templates = array('groups/single/plugins.php','plugin-template.php');
    if( strstr( locate_template($templates), 'groups/single/plugins.php' ) ) {
        bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'groups/single/plugins' ) );
    } else {
        bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'plugin-template' ) );
    }
}

function group_links_function_to_show_screen_title() {
    echo 'Links';
}

function group_links_function_to_show_screen_content() { 
    echo "Rawr";
}


?>
```

Yet when I click on "Links" on the groups page it just takes me back to the homepage! :( I have no idea why this isn't working. Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image]

In the picture I've mouse-over'd the link and you can see that it points to the right place... `wordpressdomain/groups/test-group/group-links/` however clicking it takes me to the homepage! :(

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Let me know if you find an answer to this. This has been driving me nuts all day!

Comment: nothing yet... :(

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
'slug' => 'group-links',
'parent_url' => $groups_link,
```

Use this:

```
'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->current_group->slug, 
'parent_url' => bp_get_group_permalink( $bp->groups->current_group ),
```